# Как сделать BitmapUtils с поддержкой Callback, а также с поддержкой цепочки методов

Tags: java, android

Как можно сделать класс, который будет выполнять обработку Bitmap'ов (обрезка, закругление, resize, и т.п.), который будет поддерживать один Callback и цепочку методов.

Примерно должно получится так:

```
new BitmapUtils(sourceBitmap, result -> {
 // здесь результат выполнения в UI-потоке
}).resize(500, 500).crop().round();
```

Я уже пытался сделать что-то подобное. Проблема заключалась как раз в цепочке вызовов. Не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы действия выполнялись по порядку в другом потоке (касательно цепочки вызовов). Временным решением было вызывать .join() у потоков-обработчиков, но кажется, что это не совсем правильное решение проблемы. Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Сделайте так, чтобы цепочка настраивала задачу, а выполнение запускалось последним вызовом

Comment: К сожалению, не знаю как :(

Comment: Как мне определить, что именно какой-то вызов будет последним

Comment: Просто сделайте отдельный метод, запускающий задачу и вызывайте его в конце цепочки (а-ля билдер).

Comment: А, точно. Не подумал как-то об этом))